# Issue Retrieving "Department" Attribute from Microsoft Graph API

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm facing an issue with retrieving the "department" attribute from the Microsoft Graph API. I've been trying to develop a PowerShell script for Azure Automation that assigns users to groups based on their department, but I'm not able to retrieve the department value successfully.

Here are the details:

I have set up an Azure AD app registration with the necessary permissions for Microsoft Graph API access.
I'm using PowerShell to authenticate and make requests to the API.
I'm able to retrieve user data using the API, but the "department" attribute is consistently missing from the response.

I'm at a loss as to why I can't retrieve the "department" attribute despite following the correct procedures. Has anyone encountered a similar issue or can provide insights into what might be causing this?

Please also review the attached PowerShell script and let me know if any changes are required. However, when I tried Same URI mentioned in the script with Microsoft Graph Explorer it works!

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

````
# Variables
$tenantId = "------------------------"
$appId = "--------------------------"
$appSecret = "-----------------------"
$startDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-15).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ")


$body = @{    
grant_type    = "client_credentials"    
client_id     = $appId    
client_secret = $appSecret    
resource      = "https://graph.microsoft.com"
}
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $tokenUrl -Method Post -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -Body 
$body$token = $response.access_token
$usersUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=userType eq 'Member' and employeeId ge ' ' and accountEnabled eq true and creationDataTime eq $startdate&$select=displayName,userPrincipalName,id,department" 

$headers = @{    Authorization = "Bearer $token"}

$userResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $usersUrl -Headers $headers -Method Get -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

$users = $userResponse.value

foreach ($user in $users) {     
Write-Output "Processing user:$($user.displayName) - UPN: $($user.userPrincipalName)- Department: $($user.department)"        

}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Try to use backtick character in the query for `$filter` and `$select`.

```
$usersUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?`$filter=userType eq 'Member' and employeeId ge ' ' and accountEnabled eq true and creationDataTime eq $startdate&`$select=displayName,userPrincipalName,id,department"
```

Otherwise, the PS will handle `$filter` and `$select` as properties